# Android alternative to jtable?

Tags: android, android-widget

Does android (3.x, sdk 11 or grater) has a widget similar to a jtable object?

Instead of developing one from the ground (using gridview or tablelayout) I'm searcing for a ready to use widget.

TIA,

Bob

Update: I found this excelent post http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/ about how to use a multicolumn listview.

Comment: I thought that multi column approach is obvious since you can change the list view record layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such in terms of headers, sorting and so on. You will probably have to roll your own. The closest to some extend is ListView together with a ListActivity but you have to keep in mind that with the smaller screen and the navigation by touch lots of UI paradigms from JTable dont work.

Keep in mind that each list row can include many other layout items so you can emulate multi column setups easily. You can even include images that are lazily loaded, buttons for specific functionality related to this row and so on..

Comment: Thanks. You're right about UI paradigms, but luckyly, we are developing for tablets, so right now, using a table is alright and a nice way to present information.