# Grid for android similar to JTable

Tags: android

I'm new to android building my first app.My question is  if there is a widget like a JTable(from Java) or a dataGrid view from C#

Answer (score 0):

According to this post about a year ago, no. You may have to roll your own.

[Android alternative to jtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667646/android-alternative-to-jtable)

Comment: I know i've searched a bit on my own and i've found nothing,i just posted just in case.Your thread looks promising hope it helps.I'll get back to you when i've tried it.

Comment: If this is just a personal project or a way for you to learn android development, it might be worth it for the educational benefit to create your own solution. I remember the first time I had to create my own control from scratch in C#, I ended up learning a lot more about UI design and control which has been very beneficial for me in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what JTable is but you have `GridView` in Android .

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html